# Links (without /index in them) are not pointing to index of that subdirectory

Tags: html, apache, mod-rewrite, static-linking, subdirectory

I've looked for about two hours for a way of solving, this to no avail:

Just to make it easier I'm providing links: `malumkose.com` `malumkose.com/hizmetler`

In the main page (first link) there is a button link to the page "hizmetler."

When I was linking these pages to one another, I didn't add in the /index or /index.html extensions to the links, and thought it would work on the server as it did on localhost.

The thing is, my site is peppered with these links - they're all over the joint! I would go and manually change these to add the file extension, but that would only cause the link to direct me to "hizmetler/index" instead of just "hizmetler."

I have tried adding the first line here to my .htaccess file, but it still doesn't point links without index in them, to the indexes of these subdirectories.

```
`DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]`
```

How could I possibly kill these two birds with one stone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't completely understand the structure for the files of your pages, but this should help for your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteRule ^hizmetler$ ./hizmetler/index.html
RewriteRule ^something$ ./something/index.html
RewriteRule ^something-else$ ./something-else/index.html
```

Then it will work as follow:

- malumkose.com/ > /index.html
- malumkose.com/hizmetler > /hizmetler/index.html
- malumkose.com/something > /something/index.html
- malumkose.com/something-esle > /something-else/index.html

If you want to force SSL/HTTPS, then add (between the enter of the above script):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That's a great workaround for this problem, thanks! But now another problem has arisen. I can't access files in those folders with natural links. So now, hizmetler/x doesn't work. Do I have to keep going down the list?

Comment: For this approach; yes. There are other more complicated options for your .htaccess that mimic the directory as the url automaticly. Also, you might need to change links and including of images for using this method.

Comment: OK, I tried fluking it by adding a slash such as this:
RewriteRule ^markalar$/^drone-cekimi$ ./drone-cekimi.html but now it doesn't work. What is the workaround for files within a subdirectory?